# ConnectionServer is not public in org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver; cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: java, xml-rpc

At two different places, Apache XML-RPC's documentation recommends to instanciate a `org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.ConnectionServer` object: [Custom Data Types](https://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/advanced.html) and [Introspection](https://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/introspection.html)

However, when I try to do it:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.server.PropertyHandlerMapping;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServer;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServerConfigImpl;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.WebServer;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.ConnectionServer;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException;

public class XMLRPCServer extends WebServer {
    public XMLRPCServer(int port) throws XmlRpcException, IOException {
        super(port);

        XmlRpcServer xmlRpcServer = getXmlRpcServer();

        PropertyHandlerMapping phm = new PropertyHandlerMapping();
        phm.addHandler("MyHandler", MyXMLRPCService.class);
        xmlRpcServer.setHandlerMapping(phm);
        XmlRpcServerConfigImpl serverConfig = (XmlRpcServerConfigImpl) xmlRpcServer.getConfig();
    }

    protected XmlRpcStreamServer newXmlRpcStreamServer() {
        XmlRpcStreamServer server = new ConnectionServer();
        return server;
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
[javac] <path>/communication/xmlrpc/XMLRPCServer.java:8: error: ConnectionServer is not public in org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver; cannot be accessed from outside package
[javac] import org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.ConnectionServer;
[javac]                                   ^
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Or is it a bug in the doc/library?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

```
    protected XmlRpcStreamServer newXmlRpcStreamServer() {
        XmlRpcStreamServer server = super.newXmlRpcStreamServer();
        return server;
    }
```